# How can i check two variables in a switch-case statement?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

The question is something like this.

You are given a cubic dice with 6 faces. All the individual faces have a number printed on them. The numbers are in the range of 1 to 6, like any ordinary dice. You will be provided with a face of this cube, your task is to guess the number on the opposite face of the cube.

Ex:
Input:
N = 6
Output:
1
Explanation:
For dice facing number 6 opposite face
will have the number 1.

I did it using a normal switch-case by checking all six faces and returning the respective die face number value, which passed my test cases. However, I need to simplify the code. Is it possible for me to do so?

```
oppositeFaceOfDice(N) {
    //code here
    switch(N){
        case 1:return 6;
        break;
        case 6:return 1;
        break;
        case 2:return 5;
        break;
        case 5:return 2;
        break;
        case 3:return 4;
        break;
        case 4:return 3;
        break;
        default: return -1;
    }
  }
```

```
oppositeFaceOfDice(N) {
    switch(N){
        case 1||6 : return 6?1:6;
        break;
        case 2||5: return 2?5:2;
        break;
        case 3||4: return 4?3:4;
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: `return 7 - N;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an object literal instead of a switch statement:

```
function oppositeFaceOfDice(N) {
    return {1: 6, 2: 5, 3: 4, 4: 3, 5: 2, 6: 1}[N];
}
```

Or use @DavidThomas' suggestion above which is particularly clever:

```
function oppositeFaceOfDice(N) {
    if(N < 1 || N > 6) return undefined;
    return 7 - N;
}
```

Comment: Allen, I understand the key and value pairs where you were written inside the bracket, but I didn't get this one [N]. Can you please explain how it works?

Comment: @AvonK It does the loop-up by key in the object and return the corresponding value.  So face 1 will return 6.

Answer (score 0):

Other than rewriting the codes, since in your case, the codes are very clear and easy to debug, you can remove the break statement since it's not necessary.

```
oppositeFaceOfDice(N) {
    //code here
    switch(N){
        case 1:return 6;
        case 6:return 1;
        case 2:return 5;
        case 5:return 2;
        case 3:return 4;
        case 4:return 3;
    }
  }
```